# How to add UI Elements Dynamically in android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've been looking around how to create UI elements purely by code

How can I do this?

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.MainRelativeLayout);
TextView newText = new TextView(this);
newText.Text = "HEY THERE NEW TEXT MADE VIA CODE";
mainLayout.AddView(newText);


// Set our view from the "main" layout resource
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you need to place your code after setting the content view

```
/ Set our view from the "main" layout resource
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

RelativeLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.MainRelativeLayout);
TextView newText = new TextView(this);
newText.Text = "HEY THERE NEW TEXT MADE VIA CODE";
mainLayout.AddView(newText);
```

oh and you do need to specify the type under FindViewById< TYPE >